# Does pgAdmin4 allow session recovery?

Tags: configuration, pgadmin-4, interface

I'm used to HeidiSQL, where your tabs and their states are always remembered and come back when you reopen the program.

Can pgAdmin4 automatically reopen the tabs used in its last run?